# c++ getline and will get different string(in memory) in different OS

Tags: c++, file, utf-8, ascii

In My Mac environment,

For instance, has this two files with same content.
In "file1(ASCII)", has content: "helloworld",
In "file2(UTF8)", has the same content.

When reading a UTF-8 by ifstream and getline, we will get "\xef\xbb\xbf" in the string memory. When I use std::map, the [] operation behavior will be influenced by this prefix.

From result of string, they look pretty good.
But the [] operation of std::map will take these two as different key(Mac OS).

This happens in Mac Mojave but will perform well in Windows.

So, my question is, what the Windows OS did when accessing different encoded file? or why Mas OS did ignore?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: "helloworld" string has same encoding in both ASCII and UTF-8. "\xef\xbb\xbf" string is so called BOM (Byte Order Mark) which is optional and not recommended for UTF-8. So, it's possible that in Windows file it is absent (this is hard to verify, since text editor doesn't display it). PS: You can safely ignore BOM at start of UTF-8 file in your program.

Comment: Also, according to Wikipedia, Microsoft like BOM very much and they can add its processing in standard C++ library.